# Which (if any) is correct: est., estd., or est'd.?

Tags: abbreviations

A business founded (or a building built or a monument dedicated) in 1854 might have a sign or plaque reading "EST'D 1854" or "EST 1854" or "ESTD 1854", or some other combination I haven't seen or heard of.

What is the correct way to abbreviate the word "established" in this manner? What is the correct way to capitalize this abbreviation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no single correct way to write it. Estd seems more common on older signs, or things that were established longer ago.

I've seen [Estd](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%2bestd&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi) written in many different ways:

- ESTḌ 1862
- ESTD 1824
- EST<sup>D</sup> 1817
- Estd. 2001

Likewise for [Est](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%2best%20sign&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi):

- EST. 1946
- Est. 2002
- EST 1937

The capitalisation usually depends if the accompanying name or text is capitalised.

Answer (score 6):

Heinz factories buildings (some are no longer producing) that are now Apartment Lofts in Pittsburgh has the abbreviation for Established as EST'B'D.

Comment: Indeed this is true! Photographic proof: http://www.flickr.com/photos/mrvelocipede/6105020956/

Answer (score 1):

I have seen both

> EST 1854

and

> Est. 1854

though I tend to think Est. 1854 is [more common](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_word_abbreviation_for_established).

Answer (score 0):

In most of the advertisements and signs, it is Capital, with no period

> EST 1854